# Motorcycle won't start at all

Tags: motorcycle, starting, carburetor

I have a 2006 Honda TMX 155 which has 155 cc 4-stroke OHV honda engine. It was garaged for about two years and I decided to make it my first project to get it up in running. I'm new to motorcycles, What I manage to do is clean the carb all the jets, replace all the rubber seals in the carb. The problem is the bike still won't start, I forgot the number of turns in the idle mixture screw, is that the main cause of the problem? The bike doesn't kick back when I start it using a kick start.

I would appreciate any kind of help. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!